# PostgreSQL not using any index in regex search

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the following SQL statement to filter data with a regex search:

```
select * from others.table 
where vintage ~* '(17|18|19|20)[0-9]{2,}'
```

Upon some researching, I found that I need to create gin/gist index for better performance:

```
create index idx_vintage_gist on others.table using gist (vintage gist_trgm_ops);
create index idx_vintage_gin on others.table using gin (vintage gin_trgm_ops);
create index idx_vintage_varchar on others.table using btree (vintage varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Looking at the explain plan, it is not using any index but a seq scan:

```
Seq Scan on table t  (cost=0.00..45412.25 rows=1070800 width=91) (actual time=0.038..8518.830 rows=1075980 loops=1)
  Filter: (vintage ~* '(17|18|19|20)[0-9]{2,}'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 25400
Planning Time: 0.481 ms
Execution Time: 8767.998 ms
```

There are total `1101380` rows in the table.

My question is why is it not using any index for the regex search?

Comment: That may depend on different reasons: sometimes PostgreSQL can anticipate that a filter will include almost all the rows and do a sequential scan anyway. Try a different filter that excludes, say, 90% of the rows and see what happens.

Comment: Your query returns 97% of the rows in the table. The Seq Scan is the fastest way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer was in comments; posting as community wiki.)

From the execution plan, 1070800 rows were expected to be returned, which is 1070800/1101380 ≈ 97.2% of the table. With so much of the table being in the results, using an index wouldn't be advantageous, so a sequential scan is performed.